# Selecting a value in drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript

**A] Summary of the problem:**

Trying to pre-select a users country on page load

**B] Details:**

1] I am using maximinds javascript to find out a users county.

2] I have a drop down list which contains a list of 225 or so countries.

3] Inside the javascript section of my HTMLr page, I am trying to select the users country from the drop-down list.

But the country is not getting selected

**C] Code excerpt:**

```
<select name="country_name" id="id_country_name">
 <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
 <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
 <option value="Aring land Islands">Aring land Islands</option>
</select>


<!-- including the  geoip javascript library -->
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- By default, we will select users country -->       
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById(geoip_country_name()).selected = true
</script>
```

Thanks,

**[Edit#1]**

Tried the following jquery code, but this isnt populating the drop-down list:

```
<!-- including the  geoip javascript library -->
  <script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("option[value='" + geoip_country_name() + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
 </script>
```

[Edit#2]

Tried the $("#id_country_name").val(geoip_country_name());,

```
<div id="userDataForm">
  <form method="POST" action="/UserReporting"> 
  <table>
      <!-- Printing the forms for users country, city -->
      <tr><th><label for="id_country_name">Country name:</label></th><td>
      <select name="country_name" id="id_country_name">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Aring land Islands">Aring land Islands</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>
      <label for="id_city_name">City name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="city_name" id="id_city_name" /></td></tr>     
 </table>

 <input type="submit" name="report_up" value= "Report Up">
 <input type="submit" name="report_down" value= "Report Down">
 </form>
```

```
 <!-- including the  geoip javascript library -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#id_country_name").val(geoip_country_name());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are trying to get refernces to the options by id but they don't have ids, so give each option an id of the country name. As the text must match exactly, you might be better to use all lower case, so:
<option id="afghanistan" value="Afghanistan">...</option> and then:
document.getElementById(geoip_country_name().toLowerCase())...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.getElementById` call would only work if each `<option>` in your HTML had the country name as the id (replacing spaces with "_" or something similar):

```
<select name="country_name" id="id_country_name">
 <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
 <option id="Afghanistan" value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
 <option id="Aring_land_Islands" value="Aring land Islands">Aring land Islands</option>
</select>
```

However, I'd lean towards this approach with jquery, as it doesn't require giving every option its own id:

```
$(function () {
    $("#id_country_name").val(geoip_country_name());
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and have pasted the code in "Edit#1", but this hasnt worked and the drop-down box shows up with the "------" as the selected value.

Comment: @lance Sorry about that.  Try using `val` instead.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @lance make sure the id of the select is actually "id_country_name" - I'm not sure if that was just a placeholder in your example.  I tested this and it works correctly if the value from `geoip_country_name` matches exactly the `value` attribute on the option.

Comment: your answer has worked. I have copied the code in "Edit#2" of my main posting. I agree with you the value returned by "geoip_country_name" needs to match with the option values in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById('id_country_name').selectedIndex=index;
```

where index is an integer corresponding to the selection you want.

Comment: Thankyou @matthewh for the response. I have the name of the country from the method call "geoip_country_name()" but not a index value. So for example "geoip_country_name()" will return a name like "Afghanistan" and i want "Afghanistan" to be selected.